# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jsp

I am trying to insert the values after submitting the form. While executing the Insert query am getting the below error.

**org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format**

DB : MS Access
In the table "date" column's Data Type -> Date/Time , Format -> Short Date

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String currentDateFolder = formatter.format(date);


DataBase db = new DataBase();
Connection connection_fetchProgram2 = db.getConnection();
Statement statement2 = connection_fetchProgram2.createStatement();
String selectQuery2 = "INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE ([study_date]) values ('"+currentDateFolder+"')";
statement2.executeUpdate(selectQuery2);
```

Can someone guide me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Access uses # character for date/time delimiter. Try that instead of apostrophe.

Comment: Also, Access uses MM/dd/yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd in SQL

Comment: @Erik A @June7
`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" #yyyy-MM-dd#");
String currentDateFolder = formatter.format(date);
String selectQuery2 = "INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE ([study_date]) values ('"+currentDateFolder+"')"; `
Updated the code with following "#" and the format, now getting the below error "org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: 2022 required: )
" Console value: INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE([study_date]) values ('#2022-02-16#')

Comment: No quotes! Not quotes and octothorpes...

Comment: @Erik A
Thank you, it helped.
Update Changed:
`"INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE ([study_date]) values ('"+currentDateFolder+"')";  `

Comment: You still miss the _octothorpes_. It should read: `"INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE ([study_date]) values (#"+currentDateFolder+"#)"; `.

Comment: @Gustav Yeah, thank you for the update..i copy pasted the wrong one.